# Merge tags "money" and "finance"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

These two tags appear to be synonymous.  Should they be merged, or should the tag wiki for finance be defined in such a way as to be discrete and distinct from the money tag?

[The Money tag](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) is currently defined as:

> Family finance, and how children learn to handle money.

[Finance](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) has no tag wiki entry currently.

Additionally, there is the tag: [Pocket Money](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pocket-money), which also has no wiki summary.

Should all three be merged into a single tag, with a wiki matching that of the current Money tag?  Or is there reason to have a finer level of distinction (say separating family finance and budgeting from teaching children the value of money)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, merge all 3 into Money** and set tag synonyms up for the other tags pointing to Money.  All three are effectively identical.

Comment: Just do it; this can't be all that controversial. Be sure to set up synonyms for the most obvious alternatives.

Comment: When you do merge them, please be sure to put a link to http://money.stackexchange.com/ in the tag wiki -- some questions might be a better fit there than here. It's also linked in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

**No, we should keep them as separate tags to indicate separate concepts**.

The Money tag should have the wiki changed to "Money as it relates directly to children: allowances, learning how to handle money, gifts, etc.".

The Finance tag should have a wki entry indicating that it is for "Family finance, budgeting, and the overall costs associated with raising children".